# initalization of array of hashes in perl

Tags: perl

If I wrote

```
my %modules = (
Paths => ["$path","$other_path"]
);
```

I can access via

```
print $modules{Paths}[1];
```

but I will initialize it like

```
my @rray = ("$path", "$other_path");
my %modules = ( Paths => @rray);
```

but then it does not work with

```
print $modules{Paths}[1];
```

what do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to the `@rray` array.

```
my %modules = (Paths => \@rray);
```

You might want to check [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Making-References) and [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS)

```
my @rray = ("$path", "$other_path");
my %modules = ( Paths => @rray);
```

results in flattened list of key/value pairs,

```
my %modules = ("Paths", "$path", "$other_path");
#              key1      value1  key2
```

which in this particular case would warn `Odd number of elements in hash assignment` under warnings.